# Java RMI Replication

Tags: java, replication, rmi

Which are the best methods for implementing replication on servers using Java RMI. I want to implement a fault tolerance system but a requirement is to user Java RMI. I already developed an app using a single server. Now I need to use another server that gonna receive the replicated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RMI/IIOP and a Java ORB that supports your requirement.